# why is my java rendering engine not updating the window?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm making a renderer for a game and everything works but the jpanel wont update and when it does it sometimes renders out of order.

examples :

[image: how its supposed to look]

[image: after I maximize the screen]

here is the code that renders the frame :

```
static Container c;
static JFrame f;
static ArrayList<renderable_object> objs = new ArrayList<>();

public void main () {
    Image iconI = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(icon);  

    f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.getContentPane().add(new canvas());
    c = f.getContentPane();
}

class canvas extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Dimension size = getSize();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

        for (renderable_object part : objs) {       
            g.setColor(part.c);
            if (part.type == 1) {
                g.drawLine(part.i,part.j,part.k,part.l);
            } else if (part.type == 2) {
                g.drawOval(part.i,part.j,part.k,part.l);
            } else if (part.type == 3) {
                g.drawRect(part.i,part.j,part.k,part.l);
            } else if (part.type == 4) {
                g.drawString(part.name,part.k,part.l);
            }
        }

        objs.clear();
    }
}

class renderable_object {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;

    int type = 0;

    String name = "";

    Color c = new Color(0,0,0);
}
```

}

the arraylist assures that the renderer correctly orders the objects.

help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. And don't use "Canvas", that is an AWT class. Use a more descriptive name. 2) Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible 3) A painting method should NOT change the state of the class. That is you should NOT clear the ArrayLIist, only paint whatever is contained in the ArrayList. 4) You should NOT be using static variables and methods. 
 Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: To reiterate what camickr said: Remove `objects.clear();` from your painting method.  You have no control over how often painting occurs.  It can be caused by any number of user actions, like moving the window, lowering or raising the window, even moving the mouse over the window.  Clear that list in your program’s logic, not in a painting method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue I'm seeing is that you're not calling `super.paint(g);` as the first thing in your custom `paint` method.
When using a JComponent, you can use it's built in double buffering funtionality though. However, this functionailty doesn't work with the `paint` method, but with the `paintComponent` method, thus you should replace your current solution with one like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // your drawing code here
}
```

and in the main update:

```
f.repaint();
```

Comment: After implementing the above suggestion you still need to invoke `fillRect(...)`, not drawRect(...). A JComponent doesn't have any default custom painting so you need to clear the background yourself.